# How to adjust image and text location in a table?

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to create a long-table which contains images in two columns and number in third.
This is the code I used:

```
\begin{lontable}[h]{c|c|c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{sample.png}
    & \includegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{WM.png} & $1.0$ \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
```

I'm uploading the output for one row. I want to set the chess board image in the middle of the cell and the number 1.0 in the middle of the cell too. In picture, the red boxes are the locations where I want the image and text to be.
Which commands should I use to adjust elements in the table?[image]

Comment: Try `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{...}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of `\adjustimage` from the `adjustbox` package this is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
{
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
    \begin{longtable}[h]{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|c|}
    \hline
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}
    & \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & $1.0$   \\ 
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is working perfectly.

Comment: @Wave_Rider03, you cam accept answer (by clicking check mark at top left side of answer). With this you give recognition to people, who help you and move your question to group of solved questions.